# Getting error when updating the membership scope for each group

Tags: 2013-sp1, database, user-management

Created user in the Tridion 2013 sp1 and adding groups for the user and updating the membership scope for the user. While saving the user getting error :-
A database error occurred while updating stored procedures "EDA _trustees_update" violation of unique key constarint and AK_Trustees_Roles cannot insert duplicate key in object.

Please help me out what is the root cause for this.

Comment: Have you tried these steps one at a time or are you doing them all in one go - if the latter, try one at a time and check what fails - also it would be useful to include the logs. Have you any GUI extensions or events system code running. Is this an upgrade, a copy of a previous system or a new implementation?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Downvoted, because the question appears to be abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that you are trying to add the same thing twice. As this happens when you add the user, the first thing you should check is that the user you are adding doesn't already exist.